# Sorting by max value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this in an Oracle DB:

```
TransactionID       Customer_id       Sequence       Activity
----------         -------------     ----------     -----------
1                  85                1              Forms
2                  51                2              Factory
3                  51                1              Forms
4                  51                3              Listing
5                  321               1              Forms
6                  321               2              Forms
7                  28                1              Text
8                  74                1              Escalate
```

And I want to be able to sort out all rows where `sequence` is the highest for each `customer_id`.
I there a `MAX()` function I could use on sequence but based on `customer_id` somehow?

I would like the result of the query to look like this:

```
TransactionID       Customer_id       Sequence       Activity
----------         -------------     ----------     -----------
1                  85                1              Forms
4                  51                3              Listing
6                  321               2              Forms
7                  28                1              Text
8                  74                1              Escalate
```

Comment: just use `max() then group by` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
inner join
(
  select customer_id, max(Sequence) mseq
  from your_table
  group by customer_id

) t2 on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id and t1.sequence = t2.mseq
```

Comment: This is the best solution since it lets you get the proper transactionID. Using MAX with GROUP BY will force you to exclude TransactionID from the result.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks Tobberoth!

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c300d/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( TransactionID, Customer_id, Sequence, Activity ) AS
          SELECT 1, 85,  1, 'Forms' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 51,  2, 'Factory' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 51,  1, 'Forms' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 51,  3, 'Listing' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 321, 1, 'Forms' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 321, 2, 'Forms' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 28,  1, 'Text' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 74,  1, 'Escalate' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  MAX( TransactionID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Sequence ) AS TransactionID,
  Customer_ID,
  MAX( Sequence ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Sequence ) AS Sequence,
  MAX( Activity ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Sequence ) AS Activity
FROM  tbl
GROUP BY Customer_ID
ORDER BY TransactionID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c300d/6/0)**:

```
| TRANSACTIONID | CUSTOMER_ID | SEQUENCE | ACTIVITY |
|---------------|-------------|----------|----------|
|             1 |          85 |        1 |    Forms |
|             4 |          51 |        3 |  Listing |
|             6 |         321 |        2 |    Forms |
|             7 |          28 |        1 |     Text |
|             8 |          74 |        1 | Escalate |
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
with cte as
(
    select Customer_id,MAX(Sequence) as p from Tablename group by Customer_id
)
select b.* from cte a  join Tablename b on a.p = b.Sequence where a.p = b.Sequence and a.Customer_id=b.Customer_id order by b.TransactionID
```